# What is the proper way to implement enum to manage constants in Java?

Tags: java, enums

After doing some research, I see since java 1.5 it is preferable to manage constants (or key properties) in enum which are declared in a "constant" class.

I'd like to know what is the proper way to implement these enum to get as simple as possible the value of an element of an enum whatever its type.

Example : is it possible to have the value of "Constant.Messages.WARNING" where Messages is :

```
public enum Messages {

    WARNING("main.message.warning")

}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Any sources for *why* `enum` is preferred over just having `static final`s? I do see the benefit for a *fixed, finite* set such as `NORTH,EAST,SOUTH,WEST` so you cannot set the value to a fifth. But for e.g. warning messages?

Comment: See the second half of this page http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html

Comment: `enum`s are preferable when you have a fixed number of names instances of a class. e.g. a Singleton.  It is cleaner and gives more functionality.

Comment: I see this example which is interesting. There is an answer to explain why enum can be a good practice [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1858829/static-string-constants-vs-enum-in-java-5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1858829/static-string-constants-vs-enum-in-java-5)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can customize enums as other classes in Java with few exceptions.

I'll use the same example, but it uses `toString` without `getMessage`, so you can use enums in those places where `toString` is called (for example, in `System.out.println` or any logging methods).

```
public enum Messages
{
    WARNING("main.message.warning"),
    ERROR("main.message.error");

    private final String message;

    // Parameters to the enum constructors are the ones in the enum "definition"
    Messages(final string message)
    {
        this.message = message;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return message;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. All answers were similar, but thank you everybody.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it by implementing a few methods. You will need a constructor and a getter:

```
public enum Messages {
    WARNING("main.message.warning");

    private String message;

    Messages (String message) { this.message = message; }

    public String get() { return this.message; }
}
```

Now you can write:

```
String msg = Messages.WARNING.get();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public enum Messages {

    WARNING("main.message.warning")
    private String message;
    Messages(String message) {
        this.message = message
    }
    String getMessage() {
        return this.message;
    }
}
```

and afterall you can

```
Messages.WARNING.getMessage()
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is, but in this case this `"main.message.warning"` is an instance member of the enum:

```
public enum Messages
{
    WARNING("main.message.warning"),
    ERROR("main.message.error");

    private final String message;

    // Parameters to the enum constructors are the ones in the enum "definition"
    Messages(final string message)
    {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public String getMessage()
    {
        return message;
    }
}
```

Note also that all of these constructors are called at JVM startup time; when your program is "ready to go", the enum values are all there.

Answer (score 0):

The Java compiler does some magic behind the scenes, so `enum`s feel a bit odd when you encounter them. You can add arbitrary additional data using a private constructor, for example:

```
public enum Messages {

    WARNING("main.message.warning");

    private final String key;

    private Messages(String key) { this.key = key; }
    public String getKey() { return key; }
}
```

Comment: @fge it is: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8.3-310