# any difference between declaring static strings versus enums

Tags: java

Is there any difference in declaring static strings versus Enums. example:

```
public static final String SUNDAY = "SUNDAY";
```

or

```
enum WEEK
{
    SUNDAY;
}
```

Comment: Yes. One is a `String`, the other is an `enum`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1858927/2610743 - That will give you a lot of information about when to use typical constants and when to use Enums.

Comment: This is highly subjective. Theorical differences? Many. Practical differences? pretty few in the context you intend to use them (you can even switch strings in Java 1.7+).

Answer (score 2):

If your app deals with days of the week as a type, then using an enum maintains type safety, preventing you from making mistakes when handling days of the week.  If you make it a string, your date class could just as easily print "Today is JOE SCHMOE, July 23rd."

Answer (score 1):

Using an enum scopes the name.  You have to write `WEEK.SUNDAY` instead of just `SUNDAY`, which will make your code cleaner.  Also before 1.7, you could not use strings in switch statements.