# Defining as constants in Java

Tags: java

```
list.loadRequestParms(request, 'a', 20);
```

This method takes three parameters

1. a request object.
2. a char
3. an integer

Now how to define these as constants somewhere and use it in this method.

Comment: It really looks like a homework, and I didn't understand what your want to do.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the best way to implement constants in Java ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/66066/what-is-the-best-way-to-implement-constants-in-java)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I understand what you mean, but more detail would have been useful.

```
static final Request MY_REQUEST_CONST = someRequest;
static final char MY_A_CONST = 'a';
static final int MY_INT_CONST = 20;

list.loadRequestParms(MY_REQUEST_CONST, MY_A_CONST, MY_INT_CONST);
```

Some things to note. A constant in Java is created by the final static keywords. Convention suggests that constant variable names are uppercase.

Comment: static and final is what makes a constant in Java. Static means that it is shared by all instances of the Object, rather than creating a new copy for each instance (which is pointless if it is constant), and final means it cannot change (which is required for a constant).

Answer (score 2):

How to define constants in Java - [tutorial](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0020__Language/Defineconstant.htm).

Passing parameters in Java - [an article](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/java/passing.html).

Answer (score 0):

Constants? You mean variables that don't change and are `final`? Same copy of which lasts all throughout, i.e. are `static`? And they can also be `public`ly accessible.

http://www.devx.com/tips/Tip/12829

```
public class MaxUnits {
   public static final int MAX_UNITS = 25;
}
```