# How to capture variable inside lambda

Tags: c++, lambda, c++14

I have code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23030267/custom-sorting-a-vector-of-tuples?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa):

```
std::sort(begin(v), end(v), [](auto const &t1, auto const &t2) {
        return get<0>(t1) < get<0>(t2); // or use a custom compare function
});
```

I wanted to sort tuple multiple times so I wrote this code:

```
int k = 10;
while(k--){
    std::sort(begin(v), end(v), [](auto const &t1, auto const &t2) {
    return get<k>(t1) < get<k>(t2); // or use a custom compare function
    });
}
```

but I get error `error: ‘k’ is not captured`. I tried to do it in this way:

```
int k = 10;
while(k--){
    std::sort(begin(v), end(v), [&k](auto const &t1, auto const &t2) {
    return get<k>(t1) < get<k>(t2); // or use a custom compare function
    });
}
```

but it is not the proper way and error `error: the value of ‘k’ is not usable in a constant expression` occurs.

How to capture `k` variable?

Comment: You capture it by reference and that is okay, you can also capture by value by removing the `&`. Your problem is, that `k` is not a compile time constant, which is required for the template.

Comment: Unrelated, but I guess you may want `std::stable_sort` instead of `std::sort`.

Comment: Also tangentially related, but if you want a reverse lexicographical sort, you don't need to invoke a sorting algorithm numerous times

Comment: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/05ab22354dd1b570

Comment: @StoryTeller Yes, I have task to do this kind of sort in simplest and shortest way.

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki What if I have tuples with more values? For example `std::vector<std::tuple<int, int, int, int, int>>`

Comment: There is no simple solution for this, as which `operator<` needs to be called depends on the specific type of the tuple template argument. This needs to be known compile-time. I.e. you need a templated function. BTW, Why are you using `std::tuple<int, int, int, int, int>` and not `std::array<int, 5>`? That would solve your issues.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`std::get`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/get) only accepts a template argument which is an [expression whose value that can be evaluated at compiling time](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLTBW_2.3.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r3.cbclx01/template_non-type_arguments.htm). 
You can't use `k`, because it is a variable that changes value.

```
std::sort(begin(v), end(v), [](auto const &t1, auto const &t2) {
    const int k = 3;
    return std::get<k>(t1) < std::get<k>(t2); // or use a custom compare function
});
```

As I wrote in the comments, I know `const int = 3` will shadow the `k` value outside of the lambda expression, but this example shows that `get` will work when it it receives a compiling time constant value. 
For example, if you try to set `k = 5`, for example where `v` only has 4 tuple parameters, the compiler will give an error because it knows that this is out of range.

The following code will give an error, but if `k` is set to 3, it will work

```
std::vector<std::tuple<int, int, int, int>> v;
std::sort(begin(v), end(v), [](auto const &t1, auto const &t2) {
            const int k = 5;
            return std::get<k>(t1) < std::get<k>(t2); // or use a custom compare function
        });
```

Comment: `k` is still not a constant expression... I think

Comment: NVM, it is in this example. Though initializing `k` from a run-time value would still make this ill-formed, even if it's const.

Comment: `k` is the loop counter, shadowing it with a inner constant variable (hardcoded to 3) will remove the compile time error, but will give a wrong result.

Comment: @mch yes i know that, i wanted to show that the get must use a constant value that can be evaluated at compiling time, and that the OP code will not work as he want it to work

Answer (score 5):

As mch said in the comment, the problem is that `k` is not a compile time constant.

For a compile time constant, to iterate from `N` to `0`, you may need template and recursion:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <tuple>
#include <type_traits>
#include <vector>

using namespace std; // just for simplify, and not recommended in practice

template <size_t N, typename Iterator, enable_if_t<N == 0, int> = 0>
void foo(Iterator begin, Iterator end)
{
    sort(begin, end,
        [](const auto &t1, const auto &t2) {
            return get<0>(t1) < get<0>(t2); 
        }
    );
}

template <size_t N, typename Iterator, enable_if_t<N != 0, int> = 0>
void foo(Iterator begin, Iterator end)
{
    sort(begin, end,
        [](const auto &t1, const auto &t2) {
            return get<N>(t1) < get<N>(t2); 
        }
    );
    foo<N - 1>(begin, end);
}

int main()
{
    vector<tuple<int, int>> v{{0, 1}, {0, 0}, {1, 1}};
    foo<1>(v.begin(), v.end());

    // posible results:
    // {0, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 1}
    // {0, 1}, {0, 0}, {1, 1} // impossible if use std::stable_sort instead
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <tuple>
#include <utility>
#include <cstddef>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstddef>
#include <iterator>

template <std::size_t I, typename It, typename F>
void sort_tuple(It it, It end, F f)
{
    std::stable_sort(it, end, [f](const auto& t1, const auto& t2)
    {
        return f(std::get<I>(t1), std::get<I>(t2));
    });
}

template <typename It, typename F, std::size_t... Is>
void sort_tuple(It it, It end, F f, std::index_sequence<Is...>)
{
    int dummy[] = { 0, (sort_tuple<sizeof...(Is) - Is - 1>(it, end, f), 0)... };
    static_cast<void>(dummy);
}

template <typename It, typename F>
void sort_tuple(It it, It end, F f)
{
    sort_tuple(it, end, f, std::make_index_sequence<
            std::tuple_size<typename std::iterator_traits<It>::value_type>::value
                           >{});
}
```

Test:

```
std::vector<std::tuple<int, int, int>> v{ {2,1,2}, {2,2,2}, {3,2,1}
                                        , {1,1,1}, {1,2,1}, {2,2,1} };

sort_tuple(begin(v), end(v), [](const auto& t1, const auto& t2)
{
    return t1 < t2;
});

for (auto& t : v)
{
    std::cout << std::get<0>(t) << " " << std::get<1>(t) << " " << std::get<2>(t) << std::endl;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a3b141102f0a33dc)

Comment: Thank you for resolving my problem. I was hoping that there exist simpler solution for that.

Comment: Please don't post code-only answers. Explain what you are doing and why it works.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `k` as a template argument so it must be available at compile time. One way to do this by making it a `constexpr`:

```
constexpr int k = 1;
int j = k;

while(j--){
    std::sort(begin(v), end(v), [&k](auto const &t1, auto const &t2) {
    return get<k>(t1) < get<k>(t2); // or use a custom compare function
    })
}
```

Comment: I am pretty sure that `while(k--){` will not compile with `constexpr int k = 1;`

Comment: @mch - thanks for spotting that - edited answer accordingly

Comment: Good idea. Didn't think of that.

Comment: Unfortunately I still have the error: `the value of ‘k’ is not usable in a constant expression`. C++14 standard.

Answer (score 0):

Template non-type arguments must be compile time constants.  `int k=0;` is not a compile time constant.

```
template<std::size_t...Is>
auto index_over(std::index_sequence<Is...> ={}){
  return [](auto&&f)->decltype(auto){
    return f( std::integal_constant<std::size_t,Is>{}... );
  };
}
template<std::size_t N>
auto index_upto(std::integral_constant<N> ={}){
  return index_over(std::make_index_sequence<N>{});
}
```

these are helpers to get efficient compile time values from 0 up to `N-1`.

```
auto foreacher=[](auto&&f){
  return [f](auto&&...args){
    using discard=int[];
    (void)discard{0,(void(
      f(decltype(args)(args))
    ),0)...};
  };
};
```

the above is obscure [c++14](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b14) to replace short [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17) code.  `foreacher(f)` returns a function `g`.  `g(a,b,c)` does `f(a)` then `f(b)` then `f(c)`.

Now glue it together:

```
auto sort_v_by_k=[&](auto k){
  std::sort(begin(v), end(v), [](auto const &t1, auto const &t2) {
    return get<k>(t1) < get<k>(t2); // or use a custom compare function
  });
};
index_upto<11>()( foreacher( [&](auto k){
  sort_v_by_k( std::integral_constant<std::size_t, 11-k >{} );
}));
```

and ignoring typos, done.