parallelize double for loop construct for combinations w/o replacement
Unfortunately this is my first openmp attempt. I have a very rough code, that started out as a proof of concept attempt and has yet to be polished (with 50 grit).
I have a container of items and utilize two for loops to find pairs of combinations.
For instance, if I have 10 items (a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j), I want to find things like the group {(a),(b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i)} and {(b,c),(a,d,e,f,g,h,i,j)}. (these letters are actually tuples)
nCr:
n is fixed (like 10)
for(cntr=1;cntr<n,cntr++)
  // This outer for loop basically sets nCi, eg i=1 gives
  //  (a)
  //  (b)
  //  etc,
  //  and for i=2 gives
  //  (a,b)
  //  (a,c)
  //  ...
  //  (i,j)
  // then for each of these collections, a pair is built (it and its Set complement) 
  // and pushed onto a new container. So take the given choice as nCi
  for(inctr=1;inctr<length(nCi);inctr++)
    vectorA = nCi
    vectorB = complement(vectorA)

This is probably clearer from the output or the code.
THIS SET vvt3[0] HAS 10 ELEMENTS.

[  <1, _one, 0.1>,  <2, _two, -0.2>,  <3, _three, 0.3>,  <4, _four, 0.4>,  <5, _five, 0.5>,  <11, _eleven, 0.11>,  <22, _twenty_two, 0.22>,  <33, _thirty_three, 0.33>,  <44, _forty_four, 0.44>,  <55, _fifty_five, 0.55>,  ]

(vvt4): (just before getAllCombinations())...    [[<>,<>,<>],[<>,<>,<>],...]


Number of threads within parallel block: 0


(cntr: 1)

Following is vvt4 (raw combinations): 
[
[  <1, _one, 0.1>,  ],
[  <2, _two, -0.2>,  ],
[  <3, _three, 0.3>,  ],
[  <4, _four, 0.4>,  ],
[  <5, _five, 0.5>,  ],
[  <11, _eleven, 0.11>,  ],
[  <22, _twenty_two, 0.22>,  ],
[  <33, _thirty_three, 0.33>,  ],
[  <44, _forty_four, 0.44>,  ],
[  <55, _fifty_five, 0.55>,  ],
]

(inctr: 0)  ...sorting vvt4[0] set by 1st argument (int)... [<>,<>,<>]

Following is sorted vvt4[0]: 
[  <1, _one, 0.1>,  ]

Following is vvt after each successive complement pair is added to vvt
[
[  <1, _one, 0.1>,  ],
[  <2, _two, -0.2>,  <3, _three, 0.3>,  <4, _four, 0.4>,  <5, _five, 0.5>,  <11, _eleven, 0.11>,  <22, _twenty_two, 0.22>,  <33, _thirty_three, 0.33>,  <44, _forty_four, 0.44>,  <55, _fifty_five, 0.55>,  ],
]

(inctr: 1)  ...sorting vvt4[1] set by 1st argument (int)... [<>,<>,<>]

Following is sorted vvt4[1]: 
[  <2, _two, -0.2>,  ]

Following is vvt after each successive complement pair is added to vvt
[
[  <1, _one, 0.1>,  ],
[  <2, _two, -0.2>,  <3, _three, 0.3>,  <4, _four, 0.4>,  <5, _five, 0.5>,  <11, _eleven, 0.11>,  <22, _twenty_two, 0.22>,  <33, _thirty_three, 0.33>,  <44, _forty_four, 0.44>,  <55, _fifty_five, 0.55>,  ],
[  <2, _two, -0.2>,  ],
[  <1, _one, 0.1>,  <3, _three, 0.3>,  <4, _four, 0.4>,  <5, _five, 0.5>,  <11, _eleven, 0.11>,  <22, _twenty_two, 0.22>,  <33, _thirty_three, 0.33>,  <44, _forty_four, 0.44>,  <55, _fifty_five, 0.55>,  ],
]

(inctr: 2)  ...sorting vvt4[2] set by 1st argument (int)... [<>,<>,<>]
...
...
...
(inctr: 9)  ...sorting vvt4[9] set by 1st argument (int)... [<>,<>,<>]

Following is sorted vvt4[9]: 
[  <55, _fifty_five, 0.55>,  ]

Following is vvt after each successive complement pair is added to vvt
[
[  <1, _one, 0.1>,  ],
[  <2, _two, -0.2>,  <3, _three, 0.3>,  <4, _four, 0.4>,  <5, _five, 0.5>,  <11, _eleven, 0.11>,  <22, _twenty_two, 0.22>,  <33, _thirty_three, 0.33>,  <44, _forty_four, 0.44>,  <55, _fifty_five, 0.55>,  ],
[  <2, _two, -0.2>,  ],
[  <1, _one, 0.1>,  <3, _three, 0.3>,  <4, _four, 0.4>,  <5, _five, 0.5>,  <11, _eleven, 0.11>,  <22, _twenty_two, 0.22>,  <33, _thirty_three, 0.33>,  <44, _forty_four, 0.44>,  <55, _fifty_five, 0.55>,  ],
[  <3, _three, 0.3>,  ],
[  <1, _one, 0.1>,  <2, _two, -0.2>,  <4, _four, 0.4>,  <5, _five, 0.5>,  <11, _eleven, 0.11>,  <22, _twenty_two, 0.22>,  <33, _thirty_three, 0.33>,  <44, _forty_four, 0.44>,  <55, _fifty_five, 0.55>,  ],
[  <4, _four, 0.4>,  ],
[  <1, _one, 0.1>,  <2, _two, -0.2>,  <3, _three, 0.3>,  <5, _five, 0.5>,  <11, _eleven, 0.11>,  <22, _twenty_two, 0.22>,  <33, _thirty_three, 0.33>,  <44, _forty_four, 0.44>,  <55, _fifty_five, 0.55>,  ],
[  <5, _five, 0.5>,  ],
[  <1, _one, 0.1>,  <2, _two, -0.2>,  <3, _three, 0.3>,  <4, _four, 0.4>,  <11, _eleven, 0.11>,  <22, _twenty_two, 0.22>,  <33, _thirty_three, 0.33>,  <44, _forty_four, 0.44>,  <55, _fifty_five, 0.55>,  ],
[  <11, _eleven, 0.11>,  ],
[  <1, _one, 0.1>,  <2, _two, -0.2>,  <3, _three, 0.3>,  <4, _four, 0.4>,  <5, _five, 0.5>,  <22, _twenty_two, 0.22>,  <33, _thirty_three, 0.33>,  <44, _forty_four, 0.44>,  <55, _fifty_five, 0.55>,  ],
[  <22, _twenty_two, 0.22>,  ],
[  <1, _one, 0.1>,  <2, _two, -0.2>,  <3, _three, 0.3>,  <4, _four, 0.4>,  <5, _five, 0.5>,  <11, _eleven, 0.11>,  <33, _thirty_three, 0.33>,  <44, _forty_four, 0.44>,  <55, _fifty_five, 0.55>,  ],
[  <33, _thirty_three, 0.33>,  ],
[  <1, _one, 0.1>,  <2, _two, -0.2>,  <3, _three, 0.3>,  <4, _four, 0.4>,  <5, _five, 0.5>,  <11, _eleven, 0.11>,  <22, _twenty_two, 0.22>,  <44, _forty_four, 0.44>,  <55, _fifty_five, 0.55>,  ],
[  <44, _forty_four, 0.44>,  ],
[  <1, _one, 0.1>,  <2, _two, -0.2>,  <3, _three, 0.3>,  <4, _four, 0.4>,  <5, _five, 0.5>,  <11, _eleven, 0.11>,  <22, _twenty_two, 0.22>,  <33, _thirty_three, 0.33>,  <55, _fifty_five, 0.55>,  ],
[  <55, _fifty_five, 0.55>,  ],
[  <1, _one, 0.1>,  <2, _two, -0.2>,  <3, _three, 0.3>,  <4, _four, 0.4>,  <5, _five, 0.5>,  <11, _eleven, 0.11>,  <22, _twenty_two, 0.22>,  <33, _thirty_three, 0.33>,  <44, _forty_four, 0.44>,  ],
]
(out of inner loop)

leaving cntr loop...

(cntr: 2)

Following is vvt4 (raw combinations): 
[
[  <1, _one, 0.1>,  <2, _two, -0.2>,  ],
[  <1, _one, 0.1>,  <3, _three, 0.3>,  ],
[  <1, _one, 0.1>,  <4, _four, 0.4>,  ],
[  <1, _one, 0.1>,  <5, _five, 0.5>,  ],
[  <1, _one, 0.1>,  <11, _eleven, 0.11>,  ],
[  <1, _one, 0.1>,  <22, _twenty_two, 0.22>,  ],
[  <1, _one, 0.1>,  <33, _thirty_three, 0.33>,  ],
[  <1, _one, 0.1>,  <44, _forty_four, 0.44>,  ],
[  <1, _one, 0.1>,  <55, _fifty_five, 0.55>,  ],
[  <2, _two, -0.2>,  <3, _three, 0.3>,  ],
[  <2, _two, -0.2>,  <4, _four, 0.4>,  ],
[  <2, _two, -0.2>,  <5, _five, 0.5>,  ],
[  <2, _two, -0.2>,  <11, _eleven, 0.11>,  ],
[  <2, _two, -0.2>,  <22, _twenty_two, 0.22>,  ],
[  <2, _two, -0.2>,  <33, _thirty_three, 0.33>,  ],
[  <2, _two, -0.2>,  <44, _forty_four, 0.44>,  ],
[  <2, _two, -0.2>,  <55, _fifty_five, 0.55>,  ],
[  <3, _three, 0.3>,  <4, _four, 0.4>,  ],
[  <3, _three, 0.3>,  <5, _five, 0.5>,  ],
[  <3, _three, 0.3>,  <11, _eleven, 0.11>,  ],
[  <3, _three, 0.3>,  <22, _twenty_two, 0.22>,  ],
[  <3, _three, 0.3>,  <33, _thirty_three, 0.33>,  ],
[  <3, _three, 0.3>,  <44, _forty_four, 0.44>,  ],
[  <3, _three, 0.3>,  <55, _fifty_five, 0.55>,  ],
[  <4, _four, 0.4>,  <5, _five, 0.5>,  ],
[  <4, _four, 0.4>,  <11, _eleven, 0.11>,  ],
[  <4, _four, 0.4>,  <22, _twenty_two, 0.22>,  ],
[  <4, _four, 0.4>,  <33, _thirty_three, 0.33>,  ],
[  <4, _four, 0.4>,  <44, _forty_four, 0.44>,  ],
[  <4, _four, 0.4>,  <55, _fifty_five, 0.55>,  ],
[  <5, _five, 0.5>,  <11, _eleven, 0.11>,  ],
[  <5, _five, 0.5>,  <22, _twenty_two, 0.22>,  ],
[  <5, _five, 0.5>,  <33, _thirty_three, 0.33>,  ],
[  <5, _five, 0.5>,  <44, _forty_four, 0.44>,  ],
[  <5, _five, 0.5>,  <55, _fifty_five, 0.55>,  ],
[  <11, _eleven, 0.11>,  <22, _twenty_two, 0.22>,  ],
[  <11, _eleven, 0.11>,  <33, _thirty_three, 0.33>,  ],
[  <11, _eleven, 0.11>,  <44, _forty_four, 0.44>,  ],
[  <11, _eleven, 0.11>,  <55, _fifty_five, 0.55>,  ],
[  <22, _twenty_two, 0.22>,  <33, _thirty_three, 0.33>,  ],
[  <22, _twenty_two, 0.22>,  <44, _forty_four, 0.44>,  ],
[  <22, _twenty_two, 0.22>,  <55, _fifty_five, 0.55>,  ],
[  <33, _thirty_three, 0.33>,  <44, _forty_four, 0.44>,  ],
[  <33, _thirty_three, 0.33>,  <55, _fifty_five, 0.55>,  ],
[  <44, _forty_four, 0.44>,  <55, _fifty_five, 0.55>,  ],
]

(inctr: 0)  ...sorting vvt4[0] set by 1st argument (int)... [<>,<>,<>]

Following is sorted vvt4[0]: 
[  <1, _one, 0.1>,  <2, _two, -0.2>,  ]

Following is vvt after each successive complement pair is added to vvt
[
[  <1, _one, 0.1>,  <2, _two, -0.2>,  ],
[  <3, _three, 0.3>,  <4, _four, 0.4>,  <5, _five, 0.5>,  <11, _eleven, 0.11>,  <22, _twenty_two, 0.22>,  <33, _thirty_three, 0.33>,  <44, _forty_four, 0.44>,  <55, _fifty_five, 0.55>,  ],
]

(inctr: 1)  ...sorting vvt4[1] set by 1st argument (int)... [<>,<>,<>]

Following is sorted vvt4[1]: 
[  <1, _one, 0.1>,  <3, _three, 0.3>,  ]

Following is vvt after each successive complement pair is added to vvt
[
[  <1, _one, 0.1>,  <2, _two, -0.2>,  ],
[  <3, _three, 0.3>,  <4, _four, 0.4>,  <5, _five, 0.5>,  <11, _eleven, 0.11>,  <22, _twenty_two, 0.22>,  <33, _thirty_three, 0.33>,  <44, _forty_four, 0.44>,  <55, _fifty_five, 0.55>,  ],
[  <1, _one, 0.1>,  <3, _three, 0.3>,  ],
[  <2, _two, -0.2>,  <4, _four, 0.4>,  <5, _five, 0.5>,  <11, _eleven, 0.11>,  <22, _twenty_two, 0.22>,  <33, _thirty_three, 0.33>,  <44, _forty_four, 0.44>,  <55, _fifty_five, 0.55>,  ],
]
...
...
...

(inctr: 44) ...sorting vvt4[44] set by 1st argument (int)...    [<>,<>,<>]

Following is sorted vvt4[44]: 
[  <44, _forty_four, 0.44>,  <55, _fifty_five, 0.55>,  ]

Following is vvt after each successive complement pair is added to vvt
[
[  <1, _one, 0.1>,  <2, _two, -0.2>,  ],
[  <3, _three, 0.3>,  <4, _four, 0.4>,  <5, _five, 0.5>,  <11, _eleven, 0.11>,  <22, _twenty_two, 0.22>,  <33, _thirty_three, 0.33>,  <44, _forty_four, 0.44>,  <55, _fifty_five, 0.55>,  ],
[  <1, _one, 0.1>,  <3, _three, 0.3>,  ],
[  <2, _two, -0.2>,  <4, _four, 0.4>,  <5, _five, 0.5>,  <11, _eleven, 0.11>,  <22, _twenty_two, 0.22>,  <33, _thirty_three, 0.33>,  <44, _forty_four, 0.44>,  <55, _fifty_five, 0.55>,  ],
...
[  <22, _twenty_two, 0.22>,  <44, _forty_four, 0.44>,  ],
[  <1, _one, 0.1>,  <2, _two, -0.2>,  <3, _three, 0.3>,  <4, _four, 0.4>,  <5, _five, 0.5>,  <11, _eleven, 0.11>,  <33, _thirty_three, 0.33>,  <55, _fifty_five, 0.55>,  ],
[  <22, _twenty_two, 0.22>,  <55, _fifty_five, 0.55>,  ],
[  <1, _one, 0.1>,  <2, _two, -0.2>,  <3, _three, 0.3>,  <4, _four, 0.4>,  <5, _five, 0.5>,  <11, _eleven, 0.11>,  <33, _thirty_three, 0.33>,  <44, _forty_four, 0.44>,  ],
[  <33, _thirty_three, 0.33>,  <44, _forty_four, 0.44>,  ],
[  <1, _one, 0.1>,  <2, _two, -0.2>,  <3, _three, 0.3>,  <4, _four, 0.4>,  <5, _five, 0.5>,  <11, _eleven, 0.11>,  <22, _twenty_two, 0.22>,  <55, _fifty_five, 0.55>,  ],
[  <33, _thirty_three, 0.33>,  <55, _fifty_five, 0.55>,  ],
[  <1, _one, 0.1>,  <2, _two, -0.2>,  <3, _three, 0.3>,  <4, _four, 0.4>,  <5, _five, 0.5>,  <11, _eleven, 0.11>,  <22, _twenty_two, 0.22>,  <44, _forty_four, 0.44>,  ],
[  <44, _forty_four, 0.44>,  <55, _fifty_five, 0.55>,  ],
[  <1, _one, 0.1>,  <2, _two, -0.2>,  <3, _three, 0.3>,  <4, _four, 0.4>,  <5, _five, 0.5>,  <11, _eleven, 0.11>,  <22, _twenty_two, 0.22>,  <33, _thirty_three, 0.33>,  ],
]
(out of inner loop)

and anyway, a container of pairs from nC1, nC2, all the way to nC(n-1) is constructed into one container.

The idea, since I have X cores, is to have a core/thread assigned to each nCi, and when one finished, move to another free one, say nC(X+1), etc. (of course the OS and other demands will dictate how many are used I know)
Should the std::sort be parallelized as well?
I found, among others, this;
Parallelize three_for_loop in C++ by openmp
which is quite similar - even the same error. I know, for instance, that these jobs need to be independent, and I feel that nC(i) and nC(i+1) should indeed be independent.
I am still learning from https://www.openmp.org/wp-content/uploads/openmp-examples-5.1.pdf and other tutorials, but did not expect to need openmp to solve this problem.
Lastly, here is a sorta-MWE. (sorta because there are function definitions, like print, that might help with debugging)

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <tuple>

#include <iterator>
#include <cassert>

#include <omp.h>

// https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/2d-vector-of-tuples-in-c-with-examples/
typedef std::vector<std::vector<std::tuple<int,std::string,double>>> myvv;
typedef std::tuple<int,std::string,double> mytuple;
typedef std::vector<std::tuple<int,std::string,double>> myvtuple;
typedef std::vector<std::vector<std::tuple<int,std::string,double>>> myvvtuple;
typedef std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<std::tuple<int,std::string,double>>>> myvvvtuple;
typedef std::vector<  std::tuple<  std::tuple<int,std::string,double>, std::tuple<int,std::string,double>   >   > myVTtt;

// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6245735/pretty-print-stdtuple
#include <utility>

// https://www.gangofcoders.net/solution/creating-all-possible-k-combinations-of-n-items-in-c/    
template<typename T> std::vector<std::vector<T>> getAllCombinations(const std::vector<T>& inputVector, int k)
{
    std::vector<std::vector<T>> combinations;
    std::vector<int> selector(inputVector.size());
    std::fill(selector.begin(), selector.begin() + k, 1);

    do {
        std::vector<int> selectedIds;
        std::vector<T> selectedVectorElements;
        for (long unsigned int i = 0; i < inputVector.size(); i++) {
            if (selector[i]) {
                selectedIds.push_back(i);
            }
        }
        for (auto& id : selectedIds) {
            selectedVectorElements.push_back(inputVector[id]);
        }
        combinations.push_back(selectedVectorElements);
    } while (std::prev_permutation(selector.begin(), selector.end()));

    return combinations;
}

// https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/2d-vector-of-tuples-in-c-with-examples/
// Function to print 2D vector elements
void print(std::vector<std::vector<std::tuple<int,
                               std::string, double> > >& myContainer)
{
    std::cout << "[\n";
    // Iterating over 2D vector elements
    for (auto currentVector : myContainer) {
        // Each element of the 2D vector
        // is a vector itself
        std::vector<std::tuple<int, std::string, double> > myVector
            = currentVector;

        // Iterating over the vector elements
        std::cout << "[  ";
        for (auto currentTuple : myVector) {

            // Print the element
            std::cout << "<";
            std::cout << std::get<0>(currentTuple)
                 << ", " << std::get<1>(currentTuple)
                 << ", " << std::get<2>(currentTuple);
            std::cout << ">,  ";
        }
        std::cout << "],\n";
    }
    std::cout << "]\n";
}

// https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/2d-vector-of-tuples-in-c-with-examples/
// Function to print 2D vector elements
void print1(std::vector<std::tuple<int,
                               std::string, double> >& myContainer)
{
        // Iterating over the vector elements
        std::cout << "[  ";
        for (auto currentTuple : myContainer) {

            // Print the element
            std::cout << "<";
            std::cout << std::get<0>(currentTuple)
                 << ", " << std::get<1>(currentTuple)
                 << ", " << std::get<2>(currentTuple);
            std::cout << ">,  ";
//            std::cout << ">,  \n";
        }
        std::cout << "]\n";
}

void print3D(std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<std::tuple<int,std::string,double>>>>& innerContainer)
{
    //std::vector<std::tuple<int,std::string,double>> finalList;
    //std::vector<std::vector<std::tuple<int,std::string,double>>> finalVecVecTup;
    std::cout << "#\n";
    for (auto current2D : innerContainer){
        std::vector<std::vector<std::tuple<int,std::string,double>>> inner2D = current2D;
        std::cout << "{ ";
        for (auto currentD : inner2D){
            std::vector<std::tuple<int,std::string,double>> innerD = currentD;
            std::cout << "[ ";
            for (auto currentTup : currentD){
                std::cout << "<";
                std::cout << std::get<0>(currentTup)
                    << ", " << std::get<1>(currentTup)
                    << ", " << std::get<2>(currentTup);
                std::cout << ">, ";
                //finalList.push_back(currentTup);
            }
            //finalVecVecTup.push_back(currentD);
            std::cout << "], \n";
        }
        std::cout << "},\n";
    }
    std::cout << "#\n";
}


int main(){

myvtuple vt1;       //  [<>,...]
auto itv1 = vt1.begin();
itv1 = vt1.insert(itv1,std::make_tuple(1,"_one",0.1));
itv1 = vt1.insert(itv1,std::make_tuple(2,"_two",-0.2));
itv1 = vt1.insert(itv1,std::make_tuple(3,"_three",0.3));
itv1 = vt1.insert(itv1,std::make_tuple(4,"_four",0.4));
itv1 = vt1.insert(itv1,std::make_tuple(5,"_five",0.5));

                                                    std::cout << "Vector of tuples:\n[<";
                                                    for (auto i : vt1)
                                                      std::cout << std::get<0>(i) << ", " << std::get<1>(i) << ", " << std::get<2>(i) << ">, <";
                                                    std::cout << "]\n" << std::endl;

myvtuple vt2;       //  [<>,...]
auto itv2 = vt2.begin();
itv2 = vt2.insert(itv2,std::make_tuple(11,"_eleven",0.11));
itv2 = vt2.insert(itv2,std::make_tuple(22,"_twenty_two",0.22));
itv2 = vt2.insert(itv2,std::make_tuple(33,"_thirty_three",0.33));
itv2 = vt2.insert(itv2,std::make_tuple(44,"_forty_four",0.44));
itv2 = vt2.insert(itv2,std::make_tuple(55,"_fifty_five",0.55));

                                                    std::cout << "Vector of tuples:\n[";
                                                    for (auto i : vt2)
                                                      std::cout << "<" << std::get<0>(i) << ", " << std::get<1>(i) << ", " << std::get<2>(i) << ">,";
                                                    std::cout << "]\n" << std::endl;

myvvtuple vvt1;     //  [[<>,...],...]
auto it = vvt1.begin();
it = vvt1.insert(it,vt1);
it = vvt1.insert(it,vt2);
//    std::cout << std::get<0>(vvt1[0][0]) << std::endl;
std::cout << "\n(vvt1): Following is a vector of vector of tuples...\n" << std::endl;
print(vvt1);


    std::cout << "\n(vt3): Following is a vector of tuples - a new one with previous two added\n" << std::endl;
    myvtuple vt3;       //  [<>,...]
    auto vt3Pos = std::next(vt3.begin(),0);

                                                    for (auto [X, Y, Z] : vt3)
                                                      std::cout << X << '\t' << Y << '\t' << Z << '\n' << std::endl;
                                                    std::cout << '\n' << std::endl;

    vt3.insert(vt3Pos, vt1.cbegin(), vt1.cend());

                                                    for (auto [X, Y, Z] : vt3)
                                                      std::cout << X << '\t' << Y << '\t' << Z << '\n' << std::endl;
                                                    std::cout << '\n' << std::endl;

    vt3.insert(vt3.end(), vt2.cbegin(), vt2.cend());

                                                    for (auto [X, Y, Z] : vt3)
                                                      std::cout << X << '\t' << Y << '\t' << Z << '\n' << std::endl;
                                                    std::cout << '\n' << std::endl;

    myvvtuple vvt3;
    auto it_vvt3 = vvt3.begin();
    it_vvt3 = vvt3.insert(it_vvt3,vt3);
    std::cout << "\n(vvt3): Final list of all items to be sorted and partitioned...[[<>,<>,<>,...]]\n" << std::endl;
    print(vvt3);

// sort:
        std::cout << "\n(vvt3[0]):\tSorting vvt3[0] set (total - before combinations - based on 1st index)...[<>,<>,<>,...]" << std::endl;
        std::sort(begin(vvt3[0]), end(vvt3[0]), [](auto const &t1, auto const &t2) {
            return std::get<0>(t1) < std::get<0>(t2);
        });
        unsigned const int Lvvt30 = vvt3[0].size();
        std::cout << "\nTHIS SET vvt3[0] HAS " << Lvvt30 << " ELEMENTS.\n" << std::endl;
        print1(vvt3[0]);    // tupPrint(vvt3[0][Lvvt30-2]);

                                                    std::cout << "\n(vvt4): (just before getAllCombinations())... \t [[<>,<>,<>],[<>,<>,<>],...]\n" << std::endl;

        myvvvtuple vvvt4;       // for storing combinations from nCr
        myvvvtuple vvvt;        // for storing complement pairs for each choose size
        myvvtuple vvt4;
        myvtuple diff;

// parallelize this somehow....
//omp_set_num_threads(4);
//#pragma omp parallel for

//#pragma omp parallel
{
//        #pragma openmp for
        std::cout << "\nNumber of threads within parallel block: " << omp_get_thread_num() << "\n" << std::endl;
        for(std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<std::tuple<int,std::string,double>>>>::size_type cntr = 1; cntr < Lvvt30; cntr++){
            std::cout << "\n(cntr: " << cntr << ")" << std::endl;
            vvt4 = getAllCombinations(vvt3[0],cntr);
                vvvt4.push_back(vvt4);
            std::cout << "\nFollowing is vvt4 (raw combinations): " << std::endl; print(vvt4);
            myvvtuple vvt;  //for storing each item from the outer loop
                for(std::vector<std::vector<std::tuple<int,std::string,double>>>::size_type inctr = 0; inctr < 0+1*vvt4.size(); inctr++){
                    std::cout << "\n(inctr: " << inctr << ")\t...sorting vvt4[" << inctr << "] set by 1st argument (int)...\t[<>,<>,<>]" << std::endl;
                    // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23030267/custom-sorting-a-vector-of-tuples
                    std::sort( vvt4[inctr].begin(), vvt4[inctr].end(), [](auto const &t1, auto const &t2) {
                        return std::get<0>(t1) < std::get<0>(t2);
                    });
                    std::cout << "\nFollowing is sorted vvt4[" << inctr << "]: " << std::endl; print1(vvt4[inctr]);
                    //#pragma omp critical (should only be pushed onto one at a time, but how to ensure proper order...?
                    vvt.push_back(vvt4[inctr]);
                    diff.clear();
                    if (diff.size() != 0) {std::cout << "\nSOMETHING WENT WRONG\n"; break;}
                    std::set_difference(vvt3[0].begin(),vvt3[0].end(),vvt4[inctr].begin(),vvt4[inctr].end(),std::inserter(diff,diff.begin()));
                    //#pragma omp critical
                    vvt.push_back(diff);
                    std::cout << "\nFollowing is vvt after each successive complement pair is added to vvt" << std::endl;
                    print(vvt);
                }
                std::cout << "(out of inner loop)\nNext is vvt showing (n,n+1) pairs of complements: (same as last - just outside inner loop)" << std::endl;
                    vvvt.push_back(vvt);
                print(vvt);
            std::cout << "\nleaving cntr loop...\n" << std::endl;
        }
        std::cout << "(out of outer loop)\n(vvt3[0]):\tSize of main set is: \t [<>,<>,<>,...]\t\t" << vvt3[0].size() << std::endl;
}
    
std::cout << "\t\tOUT OF COMBINATIONS.\t\t\n" << std::endl;
print3D(vvvt);





}

// rm o.out && clear && g++ -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -O0 -std=gnu++23 -fopenmp -fmodules-ts -o o.out openmp_of_combinations.cpp && time ./o.out

Those pieces indented all to the right are just print-outs for following the code's progression.
vt1 and vt2 are just ways of building the Set of tuples to process.
With only about 30 items, without doing the math, it is taking too long - hence the crash-course in openmp.
The compile line is at the bottom of the file and as it is takes about 2 seconds, but I never saw it finish overnight for the one I really want.

Note : you might not even need openmp. Algorithms in  usually have an execution policy as well.  It is also not an easy question to quickly answer, because that would need more understanding of the invariants of the algorithm. Other notes : 1) avoid using std:tuple, make your own structs (tuple has overhead an is semantically meaningless). 2) do not use typedef but use using when making aliases for templates.  And NEVER use geekforgeeks for reference (it is a very low quality source of information)

Appreciate your comments and effort. I will look over your notes. Possibly I can make an even more succinct question...

that would be nice. (I see I made a typo, should have been <algorithm>.  And then there is std::thread, std::async/std::future, std::mutex, std::scoped_lock/std::unique_lock, std::condition_variable with which you can do fine control of multithreading.
