# How to share class constants between classes?

Tags: java, class, constants, abstraction

I have 3 different classes that both use some constant values. Currently, I'm defining all of them for each of the class. How do I centralize them?

I tried to create a new static class with just the constants, and then use static import in my classes, but that didn't work. The class could not be imported successfully.

PS: I don't want to use enum and interface.

Comment: How come the solution with the new class and static import did not work? What was the error message?

Comment: @DaveJarvis It's a really bad practice, as I found by my research.

Comment: @CyrilleKarmann The import doesn't work, the classes don't compile.

Comment: question already asked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/66066/what-is-the-best-way-to-implement-constants-in-java

Comment: `import static foo.bar.Class.*`

Comment: @Javier That didn't work. I have a class called `constants` and I use `import static constants.*;` but it didn't work. Error: `The import constants cannot be resolved`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot import classes from the default package (i.e. the /src directory).
You need to include the package name in the `import` clause, even if both classes are in the same package.

For instance:

- Class `Main` in /src
- Class `Constants` in /src/utils

In class `Main`:

```
 import static utils.Constants.*;
 class Main {...}
```

In class `Constants`

```
 package utils.Constants;
 class Constants {...}
```