# Won't let me initialize a final constant int?

Tags: java, int, constants

I need to initialize a constant int for this program but it's giving me the error "Syntax error on token "NO_VALUE", delete this token", but "NO_VALUE" is supposed to be the name of the int.

Here is the code where I try to initialize it

```
public class DayOfWeek {
    int myMonth, myDayOfMonth, myYear, myAdjustment, numericDayOfWeek;
    public final int constant NO_VALUE = -1;
```

Comment: The compiler goes on compiling as long as the text so far could be the prefix of some valid program, and then reports an error on the next token. "constant" is a valid Java identifier so "NO_VALUE" is the token that forces the compiler to report an error. Often, the real problem is a few tokens back from the reported error.

Answer (score 4):

Remove the invalid `constant` keyword (and add `static`) to produce a constant

```
public static final int NO_VALUE = -1;
```

Have a look at the [available keywords](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/_keywords.html)

Also have a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66066/what-is-the-best-way-to-implement-constants-in-java)

Comment: My classmate told me this was not the same as constant though? Also the professor said initialize it as a constant, and this is java

Comment: Ok I changed it to public static final but it is still giving me this error; Syntax error on token "NO_VALUE", delete this token