# Declaring multiple strings in other java file

Tags: java, android, string

I am trying to declare a message protocol that I want to use for exchanging data over UDP. So I would like to declare a bunch of string constants in another file so that I can reference them in my main activity when I am building a packet. I know this isn't right because I am getting errors, but this is what I would like to do...

```
public final class PACKET
{

    // Packet Protocol Version
    public final void REV ()
    {
        final String R_1_00                         = "1.00";
        final String R_1_01                         = "1.01";
    }

    public final void CMD ()
    {
        final String STAT                           = "STAT";
        final String STOP                           = "STOP";
        final String WAIT                           = "WAIT";

    }
}
```

That way when I am creating a packet in my main activity I can use `PACKET.CMD.WAIT`, or something like that. Is there a proper way to do this? Thanks

Comment: This is one way to do it. Make your variables `public` so that you can access then directly like `PACKET.R_1_00`. Also you can try enums. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/66066/what-is-the-best-way-to-implement-constants-in-java - Has answers you are looking for.

Comment: Is there any reason not to use the android strings resources file for this? Or is it just a preference?

Comment: I think as per the answer in the above question and the codes I have seen so far, public classes are most famous with final strings.

Comment: Normally resources files contain variables that can be altered/injected by the user manually to change the application code flow. so constants are not stored in resource files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this:

```
public final class PACKET
{
    // Packet Protocol Version
    public static class REV {
        public final String R_1_00 = "1.00";
        public final String R_1_01 = "1.01";
    }

    public static class CMD {
        public final String STAT = "STAT";
        public final String STOP = "STOP";
        public final String WAIT = "WAIT";
    }
}
```

Comment: This is what I was originally trying to do. I see I had forgotten to make the internal classes static. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would use an `Enum` for this.

```
public final class Packet {

    // Packet Protocol Version
    public static enum REV {
        R_1_00("1.00"),
        R_1_01("1.01");

        private final String name;

        private REV(String name){
            this.name = name;
        }

        @Override 
        public String toString(){
            return this.name;
        }
    }

    public static enum CMD {
        STAT, STOP, WAIT;
    }
}
```