# Using Constants OR System Properties

Tags: java

I am working on a REST API project and using Websphere Application Server 8.5 for the deployment.
There are some `String` attributes like `COUNTRY_NAME` , `COMPANY_NAME` etc, which are same throughout the application.

Currently I have created a `Constants` class which is maintaining all the constants using `public static final` variables. But some of my team mates on their modules, are adding these constants entries in Websphere environment variables and getting them using `System.getProperty()`.

What i am thinking the problem in this `System.getProperty()` way is that it makes the app dependent on the Websphere Server, but mine `Constants` file is in the application itself, making it standalone, without dependency to server.

But on the other hand, if i want to change the attribute value, i need to create new EAR file of the app & redeploy, while in case of `System.getProperty()` change can be done in server, without redeployment.

So which way should i move forward. Using `Constants` file or `System.getProperty()`.

Answer (score 2):

Storing constants in a dedicated class or interface is not recommended. See [What is the best way to implement constants in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66066/what-is-the-best-way-to-implement-constants-in-java) for a related discussion.

IMO, having the constants configured as resource files is a better approach because it avoids the need to change the code in case constants value need to be changed.

Comment: But Resource file is also there in the EAR, so we need to create the EAR again , and deploy ?

Comment: Indeed. And sometimes you don't want anyone to fiddle with these things in a production environment just because its possible. I would never move constants into a properties file for the remote probability that they may change when easter and Christmas fall on the same day. If they change, other things may change too and a recompile and repackaging is needed anway.

Comment: @Harald you which one should i use ?