# Field definitions in test classes

Tags: java, static, field, final

Consider the following test class:

```
public class MyTest extends extends EasyMockSupport {

    private static TestobjectFactory testobjectFactory = new TestobjectFactory();
    private static final Date DATE = testobjectFactory.createDate(2013, 0, 13, 01, 02, 03);
    private static final String CSV = "einCsv";

    @TestSubject
    private ClassToBeTested classUnderTest = new ClassToBeTested();

    @Mock
    private ClassToBeMocked myMock;

    @After
    public void tearDown() {
        verifyAll();
    }

    @Test
    public void myTest() throws Exception {
        replayAll();

        String outcome = classUnderTest.someMethod("", DATE);

        assertThat(outcome, is(""));
    }

    @Test
    public void anotherTest() throws Exception {
        expect(myMock.mockedMethod((String[]) anyObject())).andReturn(testobjectFactory.foo());

        replayAll();

        String outcome = classUnderTest.someMethod(CSV, DATE);

        assertTrue(outcome.contains("abc"));
    }

}
```

Questions:

- Why would you define CSV (or DATE) static final? Defining it final I agree as it's constant. But why static?
- Which fields are written in uppercase?
  private static final MY_FIELD;
  private final MY_FIELD;
  private static MY_FIELD;
- Wouldn't it be better to use a static TestobjectFactory?

Edit:

I already saw that post from the possible duplicate before. But the questions I wrote don't have an answer in there.

Comment: Magic string constants can always be declared as static final. That way they exist only once and don't have to be created/loaded everytime an instance of the class is produced

Comment: "Wouldn't it be better to use a static TestobjectFactory?" You are already: `private static TestobjectFactory testobjectFactory = ...`. What do you mean?

Comment: Ok, this answers my first question. Nice one. With the second question I mean a call like TestobjectFactory.createDate(2013, 0, 13, 01, 02, 03); instead of instantiating it.

Comment: "Which fields are written in uppercase?" What is your project's coding standard? e.g. [Google's Java style guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/javaguide.html#s5-naming) specifies it for some identifiers, but that's just the way Google chooses to do it; [Oracle specifies different standards](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html).

Comment: I am asking in the sense of java standards.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the best way to implement constants in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/66066/what-is-the-best-way-to-implement-constants-in-java)