# Comma constant in internal library

Tags: java, constants

I want to use constant char/string comma (`,`) in my code.

Where I can find `static final` variable in standard library? If there is not such a place, can you point me popular external library for that?

**EDIT:** I don't want to create my own constant, I want to use it from JDK (or external library if it not exists)

Comment: You want what? Why don't you just declare a constant yourself?

Comment: You can declare your own constant

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What would be the benefit of depending on an external library for just a constant? If your not using code from that library I would advise to define the constant in your own project.

If you use the comma-constant all over the place in your code try to find a common interface/class and define the constant in that interface/class.

If there is no common interface/class create an enum with a logical name. Do not create a class or interface just for wrapping a constant.

If you need the comma-constant in a single class declare it in that class. (either protected or private).

See also [What is the best way to implement constants in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66066/what-is-the-best-way-to-implement-constants-in-java)

But if you really want to use a third-party library, you might want to look at:
https://github.com/google/caja/blob/master/src/com/google/caja/lexer/Punctuation.java

Comment: I know how implement constant and I don't want to know why it is wrong or good to create own constant. I asked WHERE I can find that literal in JDK or external library.

Comment: Well, look at the last paragraph that was added. There it is now.

Answer (score -1):

You can use this:

```
import sun.tools.java.Constants;

Constants.opNames[Constants.COMMA]
```

Comment: Depending on internal sun packages to avoid deduplicating comma is BAD.