# Weird phenomenon with Variables in PHP

Tags: php

I noticed this really weird phenomenon occurring with creating a variable in php. I was able to create a String variable, without using double quotes. This only works for single strings though. Excuse me if this question is stupid or something, I am a beginner to php.

```
<?php
$firstname = notreserved;
$lastname = Interstellar;
```

Comment: If you enabled error reporting/display, what do you get as the result?

Comment: there was no error; in fact my code ran perfectly

Comment: Can you print the variables?

Comment: yah. Using vardump() gives me this: string(4) "Case"

Comment: PHP is weird. Syntactically it treats this word as a constant, and will automatically assign it a value (that word, as a string) if you use it without assigning it first. This behavior is quite silly. Furthermore PHP does give a notification level error on this, but they are often suppressed. I guess all of this by the others as well, but I just wanted to add that it's not your fault, it's just one of the many quirks of PHP. You, as anybody else, would expect a more serious error message when you make a mistake like this, instead of auto-recovering magic that hardly ever does what you want.

Comment: There's no version of PHP that will return you the string "Case", since it's a reserved word. For a valid token, also note that PHP 7.2+ will raise a warning instead of a notice, and this is likely to increase to an error in future versions.

Comment: @GolezTrol thanks man! Coming from Java, I've never seen something like that go unmarked. What do you mean by a constant though?

Comment: Basically a variable that is assigned once and can't change: [Constants in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.php) and [How to do them in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66066/what-is-the-best-way-to-implement-constants-in-java).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing weird here. It is a common pitfall that is even [explained in the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.syntax.php).

The line:

```
$firstname = Case;
```

creates the [PHP variable](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php) `$firstname` and tries to assign to it the value of the `Case` [constant](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.php).

If the `Case` constant has already been created (by a call to [`define()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.define.php) or by a [`const` statement](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.constants.php)) then the above code copies its value into the `$firstname` variable and that's all.

But if a `Case` constant has not already been declared then the code above triggers a notice (`E_NOTICE`) that you probably don't see because, by default, the PHP is configured to ignore the notices.

The PHP interpreter is tolerant and assumes you actually wanted to write `'Case'` and forgot the quotes. It then initializes the variable `$firstname` with the string `'Case'` and this can help you identify the source of your error (the `Case` constant has not been defined) even if you ignore the notices.

Assuming you want to initialize the variables with strings then the correct syntax for your code is:

```
$firstname = 'Case';
$lastname = 'Interstellar';
```

Read more about [PHP strings](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php).

Comment: Thanks! That makes sense. :)

Answer (score 2):

See [the documentation for Constants Syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.syntax.php):

> If you use an undefined constant, PHP assumes that you mean the name of the constant itself, just as if you called it as a string (CONSTANT vs "CONSTANT"). An error of level E_NOTICE will be issued when this happens. See also the manual entry on why $foo[bar] is wrong (unless you first define() bar as a constant). This does not apply to (fully) qualified constants, which will raise a fatal error if undefined. If you simply want to check if a constant is set, use the defined() function.

Comment: But there is no error occurring. the vardump() also works perfectly

Comment: "But there is no error occurring" — Just because you have your error reporting set to suppress E_NOTICE level errors doesn't mean the error doesn't occur.

Comment: So how can I set my error reporting to not suppress this?

Answer (score 0):

You should get a NOTICE.

What you do here is assign an undefined constant. This will implicitely define a constant with the name as its value.

Answer (score 0):

it's because you have all warnings suppressed, check [this 3v4l.org result](https://3v4l.org/nVD6j) - every php version complains about it and doesn't let it print anything because it's not correct syntax

Comment: It actually doesn't print out because `case` is a reserved keyword https://3v4l.org/cO1Ug

Comment: yah you are right, I typed my name, but changed it here for privacy purposes

Comment: i didn't realize that, nice catch